# How can I force a hard refresh if page has been visited before

Tags: browser-cache, page-refresh

Is it possible to check if the client has a cached version of a website, and if so, force his browser to apply a hard refresh once?

Comment: Ok people, I should have re-phrased this one.
So, I uploaded a temp page using
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=url">
But after changing index.html to a real site, and removing the refresh meta line, it still redirects.
Can I make sure that people, including me, dont get redirected but just see the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can't *force* a browser to do anything, because you don't know how rigidly a remote client is observing the rules of HTTP.

However you can set HTTP headers which the browser is *supposed* to obey.

One such is `Cache-control`. There are a number of values that may meet your needs including `no-cache` and `max-age`. There is also the `Expires` header which specifies a wall-clock expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ready apparent if the client has a cached version. To tell the client  not to use cache you can use these meta tags.

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>---</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</HEAD>
```